# How check the requested URL in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I've written the code below in the `onRequestStart` method of my Application.cfc. So whenever a request comes before the session value creation it will always redirect to `login_action.cfm`.

```
<cfif not IsDefined("session.active")>
   <cfinclude template="login_action.cfm">
</cfif>
```

In the `login_action.cfm` is code for blocking the access of other pages without a proper authentication:

```
<cfif NOT (IsDefined ("Form.username") AND IsDefined ("Form.password"))>
     <cfinclude template="login.cfm">
     <cfabort>
<cfelse>
```

Now I created a signup page. This page doesn't need an authentication. Everyone should able to go that page by a single click, but now it is not possible without login. Can I change this by checking the `targtedPage` argument of `onRequestStart` method somehow?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Look at your cgi variables.  Pick one that indicates the page that sets the session variable, and add that to the first line of code you posted.

Comment: Just a code review note here: Rather than `isDefined()`, use `structKeyExists()`, especially if you are going to check a `session.active` variable. Also, check out the recommendations from https://www.petefreitag.com/item/834.cfm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question:**

> Can I check with this by the targtedPage (sic) argument of onRequestStart method?

**Answer**

Yes.

Using your existing code structure and making a presumption of calling your signup page `signup_page.cfm` you can do the following.

```
<cffunction 
    name="OnRequestStart" 
    access="public" 
    returntype="boolean" 
    output="false" 
    hint="Fires at first part of page processing.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument 
        name="TargetPage" 
        type="string" 
        required="true" />


    <cfif FindNoCase( "signup_page.cfm", arguments.TargetPage)>
        <!--- User is at the signup page, no need to check for an active session. Do stuff if necessary here. --->
    <cfelse>

        <cfif not IsDefined("session.active")>
            <!--- User's session is inactive, redirect --->
            <cfinclude template="login_action.cfm">
            <cfreturn false />  <!--- You should add this return in your existing code. --->
        </cfif>

        <!--- User is logged in with an active session, do other stuff. --->

    </cfif>

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn true />

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Great..., This is worked as expected. Thank you so much [user9263373](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9263373/user9263373)

Comment: One more doubt, if I have multiple cfm pages like this how can i check. Do I need to check each page with FindNoCase method. I'm asking is there any way to add all the cfm page names to a list and check the target page is exist in that specified list.?

Comment: @AbhilashShajan Yes absolutely.  You can do this with an `or` condition in your `<cfif>` statement.  Another option is to create a custom function that accepts a whitelist of `cfm`s that you want to bypass testing for an active session.